# Using infinite scrolling UICollectionView with iOS 13 pullable modals

Tags: uiscrollview, ios13, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal window, which is perfect for iOS 13's drag to dismiss gesture, because this way the user remains in the context, so I don't want to use full screen. The controller contains a `UICollectionView` which displays a month calendar, which is scrollable vertically.

The problem is, that when the user wants to scroll upwards in the collection view, the dismiss gesture is triggered instead. If I scroll down first, then can I only scroll up.

[image: Example]

I've tried to disable the internal `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (it seems somehow there is no presentedView, so it didn't work), tried to set the `UICollectionView`'s pan gesture recognizer delegate to prevent the system recognizer to fire (it turned out you can't do that), and tried to scroll the collection view on appearing a bit (ugly).

How can I elegantly convince the the modal presentation, that my scrollview isn't scrolled to the top?